# Reading JSON file in Meteor

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, meteor

Trying to parse a json file that reads something like this:
[
   {
      "Name": "Eric West"
      "DOB": 08/29/1994
    }
]
Need to parse the file so that that field Name in mongodb auto-populate with the name attribute above.

This is what I came up with:

```
var url = "http://theurl";
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
    jsonParse: function () {
        this.unblock();
        return Meteor.http.call("GET", url, data["Name"]);
}});}

//invoke the server method
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.call("jsonParse", function(error, results) {
    console.log(results.content); //results.data should be a JSON object
});}
```

Comment: You could use this module [jsonfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) to parse JSON file

Answer (score 1):

Please rewrite your code

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
Meteor.call("jsonParse", function(error, results) {
let result = JSON.parse(results.content); //results.data should be a JSON object
console.log(result);
});
}
```

You should get a **result** . YOu can access *result.Name* and *result.DOB*